# Open UWP application when an URL is clicked in the browser

Tags: c#, url, browser, webview, win-universal-app

I am developing a simple `UWP` page with a `web view`. I would like to know how can I open my application when an `URL` with https protocol is clicked in the browser. I have already tried this:

**Package.appmanifest**

```
 <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <uap:Protocol Name="https">
        <uap:Logo>Assets\Logo.png</uap:Logo>
        <uap:DisplayName>test</uap:DisplayName>
      </uap:Protocol>
 </uap:Extension>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            // Retrieves the activation Uri.
            var protocolArgs = (ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)args;
            var uri = protocolArgs.Uri;

            var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (frame == null)
                frame = new Frame();

            // Navigates to MainPage, passing the Uri to it.
            frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), uri);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;

            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```

But when a click a link in the browser I dont have the option to opened it with my app.
 Has someone an idea??

Comment: What does your url looks like?

Comment: Give protocol name something else not https

Comment: does it have protocol attached? It should be protocol://pagename

Comment: thats not possible. https is internet protocol

Comment: So how can I open my app when a link with https protocol is cliked?

Comment: As far as I know  it's not possible.You have to change your url format.. By the way edit your question to add protocol format

Comment: Here is a [list of reserved protocol names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/reserved-uri-scheme-names#reserved-uri-scheme-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind your application to internal to protocols (such as `http`/`https`).

Comment: Where is this documented? Are you sure this is true? Doesn't this MSDN article contradict your answer? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article, you can do it with URI schemes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation

Comment: I have already tried it, but it doesnt work. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is correct and it is possible to bind an app to the `http` protocol (according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app)).

> But when a click a link in the browser I dont have the option to opened it with my app.

I think the app will be called when you are activating the protocol from another app except the browser. All browsers manage `http:`, `https:` and other similar protocols internally. Only few protocols like `magnet:` links or `mailto:` are passed on to the OS. So, try checking if your app works by clicking on a link from some other app. A quick example can be making an hyperlink in MS Word and trying to open it.

If you really want to open a link from the browser in your app, there are many other ways to do it, like implementing a share contract.

Comment: Looking at the code in the question, he is already trying what you are saying here. It is just not working for him. Are you recommending something different?

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT  I said that the way he is checking if it's working is wrong. I feel it difficult to understand his English, but what I inferred is he wants to click a http link in the browser and want to open his app for that link. What I meant to say was browsers don't pass on http links to the OS. So, he should check its working using some other method